# How to connect my Nokia C7 with Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, smartphone

I am using Nokia C7 phone. Is that possible to connect it with Ubuntu One folder?
If possible can any one suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Nokia C7 is a Symbian phone.  There is no specific Ubuntu One application for Symbian, leaving [the website](https://one.ubuntu.com/) as the only method of access from that device.

Answer (score 0):

There is a unofficial connectivity suite "Nokuntu" for nokia mobiles, which might work.Im using it with Nokia n72 and it works fine with N72. I use it to connect to the internet.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nokuntu/

Answer (score 0):

There is an unofficial client for `symbians` [here](http://ubi.garage.maemo.org/).

Take a look their [download page](https://garage.maemo.org/frs/?group_id=2327).